# Process multiline text in C#

Tags: c#, multiline

I am trying to process some text with unusual pattern. The text looks like below:

> ||Names : XYZ DJ
>  Age : 23 Years
>  Location: New York; end;'
>   2018-03-20 11:59:59.397, mnx=0x0000700, pid=90c9ac, xSG:  dlgID:34
>   AppDlg:774 params:
>  2018-03-20 11:59:59.397, mnx=0x700000,
>   pid=090c9ac, lBG: OPCDManager::Response: 0x7f083
>  2018-03-20
>   11:59:59.397, mxn=0x000070, pid=f90c9ac, lBG: DlgID:37774 sess:'990'
>   conID:1 dlClose:false params:

Now, I want to load this data into a text file as below:

> XYZ DJ-23 Years-New York,2018-03-20 11:59:59.397, mnx=0x0000700,
>   pid=90c9ac, xSG:  dlgID:34 AppDlg:774 params:
>  XYZ DJ-23 Years-New
>   York,2018-03-20 11:59:59.397, mnx=0x700000, pid=090c9ac,
>   lBG:  OPCDManager::Response: 0x7f083
>  XYZ DJ-23 Years-New
>   York,2018-03-20 11:59:59.397, mxn=0x000070, pid=f90c9ac,
>   lBG:  DlgID:37774 sess:'990' conID:1 dlClose:false params:

I have tried the below code but it does not give me what I want. Instead, it gives me one long text strings instead of several rows:

```
string linesc = File.ReadAllText(path);
string[] linesx = linesc.Split('|');
foreach (string s in linesx)
{
    string new2=s.Replace(Environment.NewLine, " ");
    File.AppendAllText(path2 + "myfile.txt", new2 + Environment.NewLine);
}
```

How can I modify the code so that I get the rows above?

Comment: It is because you have replaced all new line chars with space, so they all will appear in one line. After splitting why do you want to replace the new line chars?

Comment: Debug this. The split is not doing what you think it does.

Comment: if i remove the replace function, my data remains as it was. Newline is replaced in order to make Names,Age and Location appear as a single row

Comment: You said what you want, but not what you're getting...

Comment: well, when i run my function above, i get everything in a single row, instead of three rows as shown above

Answer (score 0):

You have to break this down into several steps:

1. extract the 'global' information from the first three lines
2. iterate over the listing lines and concatenate them to the output format

At the moment you are splitting by '|' which results in `["", "", "Names : XYZ ... your whole other text"]`.

So for example (not tested):

```
string[] linesc = File.ReadAllText(path).Split(new string[]{Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.None);
// extract global infos
string[] name = linesc[0].Split(':');
string[] age = linesc[1].Split(':');
string[] location = linesc[2].Split(':');

for (int i=3; i<linesc.Length; i++)
{
    // reconcatenate new line
    string new2 = name[1] + "-" + age[1] + "-" + location[1] + "," + linesc[i];
    File.AppendAllText(path2 + "myfile.txt", new2 + Environment.NewLine);
}
```

If you also want to get rid of leading/trailing spaces you can use `Trim()` on each of the string parts.

Comment: i get an error on the line 'string[] linesc = File.ReadAllText(path).Split(Environment.NewLine);' The error is 'cannot convert from string to char'

Comment: as I said: not tested. As the error says, you need convert `Environment.NewLine` to char

Comment: splitting with full colon will create many extra fields because the the dates also have colon

Comment: @adsf as you can see, the split by colon is only used for the first 3 lines. Of course if your data have other formats than what you have shown in your post you have to adjust this!

Comment: ok. The code still produces an error "System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.'" at string[] age = linesc[1].Split(':');

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
string linesc = File.ReadAllText(path);
string[] linesx = linesc.Split('|');
foreach (string s in linesx)
{
    string new2=s.Replace(Environment.NewLine, " ")
        .Replace("Names : ", "")
        .Replace("Age : ", "")
        .Replace("Location : ", "") + "\n";
    File.AppendAllText(path2 + "myfile.txt", new2 + Environment.NewLine);
}
```

I also took care of removing "Name : ", "Age : " and "Location : " from the input.

Comment: This gives the same output. It just removes 'Names','Age' and 'location'

Comment: have you tried opening in a text viewer other than Notepad?

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this approach:

```
        string text = @"||Names : XYZ DJ
                         Age : 23 Years
                         Location: New York; end;'
                         2018-03-20 11:59:59.397, mnx=0x0000700, pid=90c9ac, xSG: dlgID:34 AppDlg:774 params:
                         2018-03-20 11:59:59.397, mnx=0x700000, pid=090c9ac, lBG: OPCDManager::Response: 0x7f083
                         2018-03-20 11:59:59.397, mxn=0x000070, pid=f90c9ac, lBG: DlgID:37774 sess:'990' conID:1 dlClose:false params:";

        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

        string[] allLines = text.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
        string name = allLines[0].Replace("||Names : ", string.Empty).Trim();
        string age = allLines[1].Replace("Age : ", string.Empty).Replace("Years", string.Empty).Trim();
        string location = allLines[2].Replace("Location: ", string.Empty).Replace("; end;'", string.Empty).Trim();

        for(int i = 3; i < allLines.Length; i++)
        {
            result.AppendLine($"{name}-{location},{allLines[i].Trim()}");
        }

        string res = result.ToString();
        Console.WriteLine(res);
```

Comment: The file will keep varying. The content is not static, only the format is the same